# Scattering of entangled states

Tags: quantum-entanglement, scattering

Recently, I became interested in scattering processes which involve an initial and final state that consists of entangled states (lets say $\left|e^{-}\right\rangle \times\left|e^{+}\right\rangle $ or $\left|\mu^{-}\right\rangle \times\left|\mu^{+}\right\rangle $). However, by looking at the literature, from both the theoretical and experimental points of view, I was not able to trace any significant previous works. Is there any place that have studied such cases (for example, computed such a cross section)?